# Disable debugger auto break on application start

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Visual studio 2010 debugger automatically set breakpoint at the beginning of Main() on application start (C# project). So each time I start application in the debug mode it paused at the beginning. Please suggest how to disable it.

**update:**
- I definitely hit "Start debugging (F5)" and NOT "Step into new Instance (F10)". Use F5 key or menu
- There in definitely no breakpoint
- It is simple and usual Main method:

```
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new ExpertEntryForm());
    }
```

P.S. It is funny, but I really can't find (and google) this checkbox!

---

### Solution

Indeed it was a stale breakpoint which didn't show up in breakpoint list and editor but was activated each application start.
Solve it by:
1. Add a new breakpoint somewhere. *(So there is at least one breakpoint in breakpoints list)*
2. Press Debug->Delete all breakpoints

So leppie's suggestion should work too.

Comment: I've never experienced this behaviour.

Comment: I recall I saw some option like "Set breakpoint on application run" some time ago. But now I can't find it in VS2010 or Project options.

Comment: Delete your *.user files. Might be a stale breakpoint failing to show up.

Comment: Rename your .exe first.  If that works find the old name back in the registry, "Image File Execution Options" key.

Comment: Thank you very much! leppie, looks like you pointed the right reason. I've solve it in a more 'buggy' way.

If you would post an answer I definitively could mark it as a solution

Comment: @MajesticRa: No problem, I have seen it happen more than often, but not quite like your `step into` described behavior.

Comment: +1: For adding a good solution. You can perhaps add your own answer, and mark that accepted after a few days. I dont mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete your `*.user` files.

Might be a stale breakpoint failing to show up.

You can try looking at the breakpoints too in `Debug > Breakpoints`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you starting the application in debug (F5) or Stepping Into the application (F10)?

If you're using F10, you will always start at the beginning of Main(). F5 will run the application until it encounters the first breakpoint.

Comment: I use F5 or click Start debugging from the menu. I updated the post.